# Обработка команд нескольких пользователей

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Я написал программу, в которой при получения сообщения я делаю запрос в sqlite ДБ и получаю `pricelist`, который содержит в себе набор из товара и его цены, например `pricelist = [('Banana', 3), ('Apple',), ('Orange', 2)]` . Бот выводит прайслист пользователю. Если цены нету, то он дает соответствующий ответ, в зависимости от `empty`

```
@bot.message_handler(commands = ['show'])
    def receiving_show(message):
        pricelist = db.get_pricelist(message.from_user.id)
        empty = False
        for product in pricelist:
            if product[1]:
                empty = False
            else:
                empty = True
            text = product[0]
            if empty:
                text += "'s price is TBD"
            else:
                text += ' costs ' + str(product[1]) + '$'
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text)
```

Если несколько людей пропишут команду, может ли быть такое, что значение переменной `empty` изменится из-за другого пользователя и программа будет, например, исполнять строчку `text += ' costs ' + str(product[1]) + '$'` даже если `product[1] = None` Если да, то как это избежать?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не изменится. Метод будет выполняться для отдельного пользователя.

И вам бы подучить Python. Зачем ненужная переменная `empty`? Зачем второй `if/else`? Это можно поместить в одну строку:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['show']) 
def receiving_show(message):
    pricelist = db.get_pricelist(message.from_user.id)
    for product in pricelist:
        text = f"{product[0]} costs {str(product[1])} $" if product[1] else f"{product[0]}'s price is TBD"
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text)
```

---

**UPDATE.** И еще лучше выводить прайслист в одном сообщении, а не каждый товар отдельным:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['show'])
def receiving_show(message):
    pricelist = db.get_pricelist(message.from_user.id)
    pricelist_view = 'Pricelist:\n'
    for product in pricelist:
        text = f"{product[0]} costs {str(product[1])} $\n" if product[1] else f"{product[0]}'s price is TBD\n"
        pricelist_view += text
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, pricelist_view)
```